# How to use memory caching in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to write a class to handle Memory cache in a .net core class library.

What should i do to set the cache instead MemoryCache.Default?
Is this method correct?

Business Layer:

```
public interface ICacheManager
{
    object Get<T>(string key);
    void Add(string key,object data, int cacheTime);
    void IsAdd(string key);
    void Remove(string key);
    void RemoveByPattern(string key);
    void Clear();
}


public class MemoryCacheManager : ICacheManager
{

    protected MemoryCache Cache => new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());

    public object Get<T>(string key)
    {
        var result = Cache.TryGetValue(key, out var valueResult);

        return valueResult;
    }
}
```